# MongoDB: sync dbs from master to replica set

Tags: mongodb

**Step1- I have following collections in my main db [running on port 27017]**

$mongo

$show dbs

> show dbs
>   DB        0.078GB

admin     (empty)

auditing

local

university

test

**Step2- Now I am creating replica using below command**

$mongod --dbpath ~/mongodb_data_dir/mongo/data0 --replSet auditlogreplySet --port 27018

$mongod --dbpath ~/mongodb_data_dir/mongo/data1 --replSet auditlogreplySet --port 27019

$mongod --dbpath ~/mongodb_data_dir/mongo/data2 --replSet auditlogreplySet --port 27020

**Step3- running mongo for port 27018**

$ mongo --port 27018

$show dbs

admin  (empty)

local  0.328GB

Query: is it possible to sync all dbs from port 27017(main DB) to replica 27018? Please help. so that I can see all the dbs existing in main db in replica set.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above post, you have just created the replica set members.
you need to add these replica members to the PRIMARY NODE first.

In main db [running on port 27017] , run the below commands :

> rs.initiate(); // this command will make this NODE as PRIMARY.

// To add the secondary replica members, use the below command, run these in the same main DB shell :

> rs.add (machineName:port);

// once you are done, on each of the secondary replica shell, exceute the below command

> rs.slaveOk();

// once you are done, it will sync all the dbs from the primary node.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am done with creation of  primary and secondary node.

My question is:
**how I can sync db from main db(master, running on port --27017) to primary replica?**

example:


`
$mongo --port 27017
$ show dbs

admin (empty)

auditing

local

university

test

`

so when I run 

$ mongo --port 27018
is should have all the Dbs running on port 27017 (master)